# not getting azure vm metric data values

Tags: python, rest, azure

I am trying to fetch metric values for a vm using below rest API :

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/aac11d2f-f03b-454e-9f65-4eb00795f964/resourceGroups/test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ubuntu/metrics?api-version=2014-04-01&$filter=%28name.value%20eq%20%27\Memory\Availableand%20timeGrain%20eq%20duration%27PT1M%27%20and%20startTime%20eq%202016-02-18T20%3A26%3A00.0000000Z%20and%20endTime%20eq%202016-03-23T21%3A26%3A00.0000000Z

But it is giving me an bad request URL. can any one help me out from this.

Comment: post the error that you are getting

Comment: I am getting this error : {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The request URL is not valid."
  }
}

Comment: @AmolShinde Did you want to use the REST API [Get information about a virtual machine extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163684.aspx) to get Azure VM metric data?

Comment: Hi Peter, No I don't want virtual machine extention, I want actual metric data of that VM like Percentage CPU, Disk read/writes per second like below : <MetricValue>
                    <Timestamp>2016-03-18T19:00:00Z</Timestamp>
                    <Average>0.32785945</Average>
                    <Minimum>0.141114</Minimum>
                    <Maximum>0.465757</Maximum>
                    <Total>39.343134</Total>
                    <Count>120</Count>
                </MetricValue>

Comment: From here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931939.aspx I can get the metric definitions but I can't get the metric values

Answer (score 1):

Finally got API's to list the azure resource metrics sharing link of rest API's:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt743622.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the VM metrics from Azure Platform, you could follow these document.

**Using Azure Storage service to storage your metrics and get metrics using storage SDK or Rest API whatever you used the classic mode or Resource Group Mode.**

Please refer to official document about how to enable the diagnostics settings on Azure Portal :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/windows-azure-virtual-machine-monitoring-with-wad-extension/
 and how to use Azure storage REST API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179355.aspx) and SDK (https://github.com/Azure?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=storage )

From your description, it seems that you used the Application Insight service to show your metrics on Azure. Actually, base on my experience, Application Insight service is in preview and it is design for your live App on Azure platform such as  Web App, Android App and soon on.

Comment: Hi Will,
     Thanks for above solution but I think from above solution we can get metrices of storage device and not of VM. If I want to get Percentage CPU, Network In, Network out metric values then how I could get from the storage sdk or rest? Could you please give me some example of how can I get above vm metric values?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931939.aspx from here I can get the VM metric definitions and not the metric values on those definitions.

Comment: @AmolShinde, Generally, the best option is that we store the VM metrics into Azure Storage. Could you please follow the tutorial(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/windows-azure-virtual-machine-monitoring-with-wad-extension/ ) to enable VM WAD extension and specify an Azure Storage account to store the VM information into storage ? if you use Linux VM, Please refer to this document(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-diagnostic-extension/)