# Is there any way to get created time of resources in azure using python-sdk of azure?

Tags: python, azure

I was trying to write a python script to get the list of resources in azure which are older than 30 days. And I was not able to find out any module or package which can tell me the time when that particular instance was created, for example the time stamp of a vm when it was created.

Answer (score -1):

```html
import os
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
from azure.monitor import MonitorClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

subscription_id = '***'
client_id='***'
secret='***'
tenant='***'

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
filter = " and ".join([ "eventTimestamp le '{}T00:00:00Z'".format(today), "resourceGroupName eq 'jay'" ])

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant=tenant)

client = MonitorClient(credentials, subscription_id)
select = ",".join([ "eventName", "operationName" ])

print select
print filter
activity_logs = client.activity_logs.list( filter=filter, select=select )

for log in activity_logs:
    # assert isinstance(log, azure.monitor.models.EventData)
    print(" ".join([
        log.event_name.localized_value,
        log.operation_name.localized_value
    ]))
```

After rearching the A[zure Monitor Python SDK](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_azure-monitor.html#get-the-activity-log), I found the difference.
Here is ge ,not le.

modify the keyword in the code (ge, not le)

```html
eventName,operationName
eventTimestamp ge '2017-10-17T00:00:00Z' and resourceGroupName eq 'jay'
End request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/delete
End request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/delete
End request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/delete
Begin request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/delete
End request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action
End request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action
Begin request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action
End request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write
End request Microsoft.Compute/disks/write
End request Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write
End request Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/write
End request Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/write
End request Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/write
```

Based on the doc, it seems your date should be escaped. Moreover, seems they take a datetime (and not a date): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs

For additional information : [not getting azure vm metric data values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177124/not-getting-azure-vm-metric-data-values)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/building-scalable-services-in-microsoft-azure-with-python.pdf

Comment: will it help me to get timestamp of resources which are older than 90 days as there is a limit for viewing activity logs in azure. And the limit is 90 days..

Comment: Azure Monitor's Activity Logs provides a history of change requests to your Azure resources but it's not necessarily the creation time of the Azure resource.  For example, a record for Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachine/write can either be a create or update request to the virtual machine.